The list view does not show events before January 1st 2024
I created a calendar with multiple views, custom event rendering & contextual menu...using hooks. And all works just great except one thing : when I switch  the list view the calendar shows only the events from January 1st, 2024 instead of 2018.
I tried many things:
calendar.changeView('list', {start: '2018-01-01', end: '2050-01-01'})

with and without time and timezone. And
calendar.changeView('listAllYears', {start: '2018-01-01', end: '2050-01-'}) 

with several variations of (here is the most extensive one) :
views: {
 listAllYears: {
    type: 'list',
    duration: { years: 100 },
    visibleRange: { start: '2018-01-01', end: '2050-01-01' },
    listDayFormat: { weekday: 'long',  month: 'long', day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric'},
    listDaySideFormat: { weekday: 'long',  month: 'long', day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric'},
  },
},

And
calendar.setOption('visibleRange', { start: '2018-01-01', end: '2050-01-01' }) 

before amd after the changeView command.
Depending on the combination, the best I got was the header to diplay the right date range but not the events.
I tracked the data and all events are provided to the calendar since 2018.
I expect the list to show the events since 2018, not only since January 1st, 2024.

Your custom list view's settings are contradictory. You can't specify that the view has a duration of 100 years, and simultaneously specify that the visible range is between 2018 and 2050 - a range of only 32 years!
Fullcalendar is using the duration value and ignoring visibleRange. By default, visibleRange only takes effect when there is no standard duration specified for the view.
Simply remove the duration: { years: 100 } setting and I think you will get the effect you were expecting.
views: {
 listAllYears: {
    type: 'list',
    visibleRange: { start: '2018-01-01', end: '2050-01-01' },
    listDayFormat: { weekday: 'long',  month: 'long', day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric'},
    listDaySideFormat: { weekday: 'long',  month: 'long', day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric'},
  },
},

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/ZYzeLXM
Relevant documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-views

You are totally right :-) It happened because at first it was not displaying all the events that I added years, then visibleRange. Now it works just fine. Thanks you ADyson, you made my day.
